# How to fix disfunctional "in" method in for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, infinite-loop, nested-lists

I have a project for school. We have coordinates of stones, where the coords are given in *list of lists* format `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]`. Part of the code is to rotate the stones, this can happen up to 6 times before we get to the initial position. This is part of the code

```
def set(self,stone,x,y):
    s1=[x,y]
    self.rotations.append(stone)
    .
    .
    .
    some code
    .
    .
    .
    else:
       h = []
         for j in stone:
         h.append(self.rotateRight(j[0], j[1]))
       if h not in self.rotations:
         h = self.shift(h, s1)
         return self.set(h,s1[0],s1[1])
       else:
         return []
```

The problem I am struggling with is the `if h not in self.rotations`. If the input is e.g. `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]]` it works, but as soon as there are 6 or more sublists, it fails to detect that after 6 rotations the stone is in the same position as initially and always evaluates the `if` statement as `True`, so it never breaks out of the `return self.set`. I also tried `h != self.rotations[0]`, but it doesn't work either. Although, if I copy `h` after 6 rotations and `self.rotations[0]` manually, and put `==` between them, it evaluates it as `True`. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it so it doesn't loop infinitely?

Comment: Please check the indentation of `for j in stone: h.append(self.rotateRight(j[0], j[1]))`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].